# OAuth client was not found using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have this error when I try to sign in with 'google' button:

> 401. That’s an error.
>
>      Error: invalid_client
>
>      The OAuth client was not found.
>
>      Request Details
>        response_type=code
>        redirect_uri=http://localhost:3001/auth/%22http://localhost:3001%22
>        scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
>        client_id="XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX..apps.googleusercontent.com"

This is my code in .env file :

```
    #GOOGLE_AUTH
    GOOGLE_CLIENTID="xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    GOOGLE_CLIENTSECRET="xxxxxxxxx"
    GOOGLE_REDIRECT="http://localhost:3001"
```

And I have this in my approutes file:

```
    /*******************GOOGLE AUTH ROUTES********************* */
    // auth with google+
    router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
        ]
    }));
And here if the config file :

oauth : {
    google : {
        clientID : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENTID,
        clientSecret : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENTSECRET,
        redirect : process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT
    }
},
```

I don't know where the bug comes from, I tried many solution in google developer console params, no results.

Comment: Hello @mitsu, your issue may be due to a few number of causes. `1.` Did you trim the leading and trailing white space from both the `client_id` and `client_secret`? `2.` Does your code work if you execute it in an `incognito window`? `3.` Are your `client_id` and `client_secret` **still**  valid? Cheers!

Comment: i checked all of that, no results :(